# Is it possible to tell the user who up-voted my question a message?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to tell the user who up-voted my question a message?

In the morning I wake up, I find last night there is a user upvote my question, but I have not find my answer to my question.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Then I got the answer, then post to there, I hope the user can see it and help him/her.

Is there a method to contact to him/her? Or whether there need a remind feature in this scenario.

Comment: There is no way to contact up or down voters

Comment: It may simply have been someone with the same *question*. Comparable to how fast homework dumps get upvotes.

Comment: @Andy How about reminder the upvoter if the post get a answer?

Comment: @aircraft There’s the favorite feature for that. There’s no need to help an upvoter by pointing him to an answer. That’s his own responsibility.

Comment: Did you consider an option that your question simply was not .... lets say comparable to average SO question and actually got upvote just because it is a reasonably researched on-topic question? (I frequently feel desire to contact people who upvoted questions... but it is very good SO does not provide such functionality as such comments would rarely positive :) )

Comment: It's so rare to get this question about upvotes instead of downvotes

Comment: corrected: "There is no way to contact upvoters, you can contact future downvoter by ranting on meta".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone who want to follow the question will favorite it (star under votes button), this way they will get all updates including answers in their profile stream.

That need not to be one who voted your question. One who voted may simply wanted to boost the question, your efforts.